# Update data in codeigniter 4 using update() or save() - Does not work because of a missing ID

Tags: codeigniter-4

I tried to update my database by using `update()`, but I don't have an id in it. Instead, I have a primary key named **kwt**.

Every time I try to execute `update()`, the query always refers to `table.id` instead of `table.kwt`

```
UPDATE `zakat` SET `nama` = :nama:, `alamat` = :alamat:, `telp` = :telp:, `jmlhjiwa` = :jmlhjiwa:, `berasbeli` = :berasbeli:, `ttlbeli` = :ttlbeli:, `berasbawa` = :berasbawa:, `ttlberas` = :ttlberas:, `maal` = :maal:, `berasinfaq` = :berasinfaq:, `infaq` = :infaq:, `fidyah` = :fidyah:, `penerima` = :penerima: WHERE `zakat`.`id` IN :zakat.kwt:
```

I need to make `WHERE 'zakat'.'id'` become `WHERE 'zakat'.'kwt'`

This is **my controller:**

```
 public function update($kwt)
{

    $beli = $this->request->getvar('berasbeli');
   
    $this->zakatModel->update(
        
        [
            'kwt' => $kwt,
            'nama' => $this->request->getVar('nama'),
            'alamat' => $this->request->getVar('alamat'),
            'telp' => $this->request->getvar('telp'),
            'jmlhjiwa' => $this->request->getVar('jmlhjiwa'),
            'berasbeli' => $this->request->getVar('berasbeli'),
            'ttlbeli' =>  (int)$beli * 38000,
            'berasbawa' => $this->request->getvar('berasbawa'),
            'ttlberas' => $this->request->getvar('berasbawa') + $this->request->getVar('berasbeli'),
            'maal' => $this->request->getVar('maal'),
            'berasinfaq' => $this->request->getVar('berasinfaq'),
            'infaq' => $this->request->getvar('infaq'),
            'fidyah' => $this->request->getVar('fidyah'),
            'penerima' => $this->request->getVar('penerima')

        ]
    );


    session()->setFlashdata('pesan', 'Upload Berhasil');


    return redirect()->to('/');
}
```

And **my view:**

```
>     <?= $this->extend('layout/template'); ?>
>     <?= $this->section('content'); ?>
>     <div class="container">
>         <div class="row">
>             <div class="col-8">
>                 <form action="/Pages/update/<?= $muzaki['kwt']; ?>" method="post">
>                     <?= csrf_field(); ?>
>                     <input type="hidden" name="kwt" value"<?= $muzaki['nama']; ?>">
>                     <div class="row mb-3">
>                         <label for="nama" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Nama</label>
>                         <div class="col-sm-10">
>                             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nama" name="nama" autofocus value="<?= $muzaki['nama']; ?>">
>                         </div>
>                     </div>
>                     <div class="row mb-3">
>                         <label for="alamat" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Alamat</label>
>                         <div class="col-sm-10">
>                             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="alamat" name="alamat" value="<?= $muzaki['alamat']; ?>">
>                         </div>
>                     </div>
>                     <div class="row mb-3">
>                         <label for="telp" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">No.Telp</label>
>                         <div class="col-sm-10">
>                             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telp" name="telp" value="<?= $muzaki['telp']; ?>">
>                         </div>
>                     </div>
>                     <br>
>                     <h3>Zakat Fitrah :</h3>
>                     <div class=" row mb-3">
>                         <label for="jmlhjiwa" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Anggota Keluarga</label>
>                         <div class="col-sm-10">
>                             <input type="number" class="form-control" id="jmlhjiwa" name="jmlhjiwa" value="<?= $muzaki['jmlhjiwa']; ?>">
>                         </div>
>                     </div>
>                     <div class="row mb-3">
>                         <label for="berasbeli" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Beras Dalam</label>
>                         <div class="col-sm-10">
>                             <input type="number" class="form-control" id="berasbeli" name="berasbeli" value="<?= $muzaki['berasbeli']; ?>">
>                         </div>
>                     </div>
>                     <div class="row mb-3">
>                         <label for="berasbawa" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Beras Luar</label>
>                         <div class="col-sm-10">
>                             <input type="number" class="form-control" id="berasbawa" name="berasbawa" value="<?= $muzaki['berasbawa']; ?>">
>                         </div>
>                     </div>
>                     <br>
>                     <h3>Zakat Maal :</h3>
>                     <div class="row mb-3">
>                         <label for="maal" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Zakat Maal</label>
>                         <div class="col-sm-10">
>                             <input type="number" class="form-control" id="maal" name="maal" value="<?= $muzaki['maal']; ?>">
>                         </div>
>                     </div>
>                     <br>
>                     <h3>Infaq :</h3>
>                     <div class="row mb-3">
>                         <label for="berasinfaq" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Beras</label>
>                         <div class="col-sm-10">
>                             <input type="number" class="form-control" id="berasinfaq" name="berasinfaq" value="<?= $muzaki['berasinfaq'];
> ?>">
>                         </div>
>                     </div>
>                     <div class="row mb-3">
>                         <label for="infaq" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">infaq</label>
>                         <div class="col-sm-10">
>                             <input type="number" class="form-control" id="infaq" name="infaq" value="<?= $muzaki['infaq']; ?>">
>                         </div>
>                     </div>
>                     <div class="row mb-3">
>                         <label for="fidyah" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Fidyah</label>
>                         <div class="col-sm-10">
>                             <input type="number" class="form-control" id="fidyah" name="fidyah" value="<?= $muzaki['fidyah']; ?>">
>                         </div>
>                     </div>
>                     <br><br>
>                     <div class="row mb-3">
>                         <label for="penerima" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Penerima</label>
>                         <div class="col-sm-10">
>                             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="penerima" name="penerima" value="<?= $muzaki['penerima']; ?>">
>                         </div>
>                     </div><br><br>
>                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
>                 </form>
>             </div>
>         </div>
>     </div>
>     <?= $this->endsection(); ?>
```

For **my model**, I didn't write anything yet because there is nothing written in my tutorial's model. When I use `save()` instead of `update()` it will create new data with the same primary key.

Comment: Your prepared statement is different from the database update query in your Controller. What isn't working for you specifically?

Comment: Can you share your model as well so we can understand the issue..

Answer (score 0):

its need id of table to update data;
your are forgot id

look at my sample example

```
function dommy($id, $data){
$myModel = new MyModel();
$myModel->update( $id, $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you update a record, you need to identify which record(s) you want to update. It should be a definition by a primary key like `id` or a definition by `WHERE` sql clauses with different columns.

It should be like on of the following:

```php
$this->zakatModel->update($id, [
  ...
]);

// OR

$data = [
  ...
];

$data['id'] = 4 // for example. You can send with form or you can get from URL.

$this->zekatModel->save($data);
```

In `save` method, no need to put `id` value as a separate parameter. Because inside the method, it checks itself:

```php
protected function save($data) {
    ...
    $this->update($this->getIdValue($data), $data);
}
```

Happy coding..